# Getting only few search results from youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

Using below URL for loading youtube videos to my web app but I get less results in api when compared to youtube.com result. How to get same result as youtube.com in api result?

```
var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=?";

        url= url + '&paid-content=false';
        url = url + '&duration=long';
        url = url + '&safeSearch=strict';
        url = url + '&orderby=viewCount';
        url = url + '&max-results=50';
```

Comment: What is the the search-query that you are running on YouTube (what are you searching for)?

Comment: any search query for example "javascript" youtube.com return ~555,000 results but in api return only 3 results

Comment: Well, why don't you just use `var url = "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + your_search_query_string`?

Comment: i need JSON for my web app

Answer (score 0):

It seem to my code issue and now working fine with below url:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=jQuery1102045083614927716553_1393136744112&paid-content=false&duration=long&safeSearch=strict&orderby=published&start-index=1&q=javascript&_=1393136744157